# Global temporary table of object type with ref attribute

Tags: oracle, plsql, temp-tables, ref, ora-00600

In oracle 9i database, I have a table of objects type. The object has a REF attribute.
When i do "select deref..." works fine.

THE PROBLEM IS:
Due to architectural issues, i have to make the table a GTT (global temporary table). Now when i do "select deref..." give me the error ORA-00600 ... [2147483647] ...

Can I have REF attributes on a GTT ? (google give me nothing about this)

If not.. how can i resolve the cycle dependence problem in GTT ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I find the solution..

GTT on oracle don't let references be type of a column.

I take the reference, put a Id (like a foreign key) and it's ok. For my porpose it work.

APC thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

ORA-00600 is Oracle's error code for unhandled exceptions i.e. bugs.  The usual advice is to raise it with Oracle Support.  If you don't have a Support account you're probably out of luck.

Very few people use Oracle Objects for declaring persistence structures, so it is unlikely anybody else has experienced this.  Also Global Temporary Tables were a new feature in 9i so it is likely that they had undiscovered bugs when combined with something as esoteric as objects.

To maximize the chances of somebody recognising your problem you need to post more details.  ORA-00600 errors are often associated with specific versions of the database running on specific OS on specific hardware.  Also you need to post the full ORA-00600 message: all the parameters can have significance.